# UNIX List files of in domain of file sizes

Tags: file, unix, variables, loops, size

I am looking for a way to get all the files in a directory (which is a variable) and then check to see if those files are in between two values for file size.

I have three arguments. A directory to analyze, a minimum value of file size and max value of file size.

I have successfully done this in a directory using:

`find "$directory" -maxdepth 1 -size +"$a"c -size -"$b"c -printf %P`

Only this prints all results on the same line. I have tried adding a \n at the end with no luck.

a is min value

b is max value

I'm hoping for an output of just the filenames on one line each and with their size next to them. 
(I had to change some of the backticking in order for the code to display properly)

How can I format this the way that I need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with `find`:

```
find "$directory" -size +"$a" -a -size -"$a"
```

---

You shouldn't parse `ls`, its output is not meant to be parseable.

Comment: Is there a way to do it so that it is also not recursive?

Comment: @MikeGarner Yes, you can use `-maxdepth 1`.

Comment: find "$directory" -maxdepth 1 -size +"$a"c -size -"$b"c -printf \n %P    I am trying to get the results on one line each, but regular print doesn't work...

Comment: @MikeGarner Why `printf` ? `find` will print file names by default.